# How to define "read only" entity for a previous migration SQL-VIEW

Tags: spring-boot

My `db.migration` folder have SQL files with `CREATE TABLE mytable` and constraints and inserts... It is a "read only" table, and "read only" SQL-VIEWs (eg. `vw_mytable`).

So, how is the simplest way to define entity for Spring without cosntraint details and desabling the automatic Spring's CREATE TABLEs for `mytable` and its SQL-VIEWs?